# My own personal Div 100% height nemisis - jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, css, html

It seems like you're nobody here until you've got your own "how can I get div to expand to height 100%" question, here's mine - (I hope it is original and helpful).

With reference to my attempts so far http://jsfiddle.net/prQcc/3/ - I have, in a jquery tab, two divs as side by side columns. I want these divs to expand to the height of the jquery tab. The closest I've come is what you see in the fiddle - the column divs expand, but to the height of the 'page', not the height of the containing Tab div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#tabs-1` is getting set to the height of `#tabs`, but `#tabs` has a `ul` taking up space at its top, so `#tabs-1` gets pushed down below the bottom of `#tabs` by the height taken up by the `ul`.

Changing your `#tabs-1` to position absolutely off of the `#tabs` [corrects the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/prQcc/9/), though padding and borders on `#tabs` is creating a small scroll bar to still appear. For modern browsers, [the easiest way to correct that](http://jsfiddle.net/prQcc/12/) is using `box-sizing`:

```css
#tabs {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Curse? I was approaching physical violence on this issue! Thanks for the solution, and especially the insightful explanation of same!

Comment: @Kevin--glad you noticed my wording change in your fiddle :-). Also glad it was helpful.